# How to resolve the Problem in the increase n vram?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, system, ram, vram

Yesterday my big brother  added a file in the registry of the
Laptop to increase the vram to play wwe 2k 16 by following some tutorial on the internet, at the last step it was asking for the memory in hexa and the person whose tutorial we were following types 1024 and selected hex form hex and decimal option we did the same and restarted the laptop but wen we opened the system information it showed that available Vram is 29 GB. We then thought that it is strange because my laptops ram is 8GB, so we removed the file from the registry and restarted the laptop but it still shows that the vram is 29 GB
Please help to resolve this issue
[Image of the registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcuRY.jpg)
[Image of system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKjl0.jpg)